# How do you use a variable in Express's res.redirect()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do this, but it isn't working:

```
res.redirect('/show/{{page.url_name}}');
```

This is the full route:

```
router.post('/update/:url_name', function(req, res) {
    Page.findOne({url_name: req.params.url_name}, function(err, page) {
        page.title = req.body.title;
        page.body = req.body.body;
        page.save(function(err) {
            res.redirect('/show/{{page.url_name}}');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you concatenate strings in JavaScript. What operator do you use?

Comment: @self `'hello' +  'world'` Concatenation worked, thanks!

Comment: Nothing is different in Node.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the string manually

```
res.redirect('/show/' + page.url_name);
```

There is no string interpolation built in yet, but it's coming in [ES6](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/template-strings/) (JavaScript's next version)

```
res.redirect(`/show/${page.url_name}`); // note the backticks
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Good to know that ES6 will have string interpolation.